# Unable to do file upload functionality in Jenkins using Robot & AutoIT scripts

Tags: selenium, jenkins, autoit

Here it is the AutoIT script

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1", "file path")
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

And Robot script is:

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

I just tried with the above scripts in `jenkins` execution but it is not working.
Can anyone please suggest me with the proper execution script.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Selenium as you've tagged the question, the proper way to upload a file is using `sendKeys`, here's an example:

```
string File = "SomeTextFile.txt";
string FilePath = @"C:\Whatever\" + File;

driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload");
driver.findElement(By.id("file-upload")).sendKeys(FilePath);
driver.findElement(By.id("file-submit")).click();
```

Your script for Jenkins could be failing for multiple reasons you have to watch it when it happens. Could be your clicking a wrong button, or you don't have an active desktop in your slave etc...